# Use rebase or merge when pulling from remote repository?

Tags: git, merge, rebase

I have a question about Git.

I cloned a remote repo. So I have a master branch on my local machine. I want to do some changes in some files. So I create a new branch on local and do my work. Commit changes on and then merge new branch and master branch. Now I am ready to push changes to remote repo.

Now, I have to pull changes from repo first and then push my changes. Is it right?

If yes, what should I use when pulling? Rebase or Merge?

Comment: That's up to you. Merge if you want your branch to be visible in recorded history, rebase if you just want to put your changes on top of the latest master (in a linear sequence).

Comment: git rebase tries make, your git repo commit graph more linear.

Answer (score 2):

Its totally up to you. But the difference between them is modification of git commit graph.

Merge Example:
Lets say i have master and issue53 branches[image]

The git commit graph after merge is like:
[image]

Rebase Example:
Lets say i have server branch and master branch like this
[image]

Git tree after performing rebase operation of server on master loooks like
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by *null1941*, its a matter of preference for the team. But usually stick to rebase when you are pulling the code. You will lose the ordering of commits but makes your git history linear.

Lets say you made a commit yesterday, but you are pulling code now which has commits from today. Your yesterday's  commit will appear at top. But it makes very easy to reason about changes when looking through git history when its in a linear fashion. Unlike the case in merge which creates a merge commit if you have local commits. The repositories with merges become very complex to find out which commit did what as a lot of commits are merge commits.

Use merge only when working on a separate branch and you want to bring changes to the master or one branch to other. Do not rebase one branch to other if the number of changes is high as you have to resolve a lot of conflicts if the code has changed a lot.